# Converting a Full HD Inspiron 9400 laptop LCD to a standalone monitor

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

Has anyone tried converting a LCD laptop monitor (17" full HD in this instance) to a stand-alone monitor? Are there any converters that one can buy to send DVI or VGA signals to the plug that is used to connect said LCD to the laptop motherboard?

My laptop is the infamous Dell Inspiron 9400 (1705) model. They can have awesome monitors but if you check out ebay, there are many there for sale for little to nothing since the graphic cards fault unsually often in those machines. I'd like to be able to use the LCD and just scrap the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an LCD Controller and a cable from the controller to panel. These guys will apparently help - http://www.agilentpixel.com/ (according to tabletmod.com)

.. but LCDs are so cheap now, you really need to consider if this is an appropriate way to spend money

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not easy. You will need a VGA controller board and likely custom wiring and power supply. The issue is not all LCDs conform to specs so there is no garuntee it will work. I did find this link that links a forum (in french) where they did this so it may be a good place to start.

http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2006/03/using_a_laptop_lcd_with_a.html

Comment: Yes, I had already googled up that page. Hoping to see if there is someone that knows a bit more about the process and could point more things out.

Answer (score 0):

Search for *VGA to LVDS* converters. Then, if you can get one with the correct cable slot, um, connect the panel and the backlight :)

See, for example, http://www.instructables.com/id/Laptop-Converted-to-2nd-Monitor/