# How do I buy a standalone LCD Inverter? (For Science)

Tags: laptop, vga, lcd, computer-science

## I was searching Ebay for an LCD inverter to connect a naked laptop LCD to a VGA port... for science.

Some things I know, some things I don't.
But for the sake of simplicity and ADHD... ill spare you the essay. :)

1. Simply put: Im trying to take a **laptop LCD and turn it into a VGA display**

   ## (For science)
2. I know there are different connectors in laptop LCDs, thus why they are not interchangable. Are they different  **[industrial standards]**  or are they all **[unique proprietary connectors]**?
3. 1 lamp, 2 lamp 3 or 4? Lamp as in backlight?

## The Following is for the sake of Google searchers benefit, in case they are looking to do something similar and need help.

-- More specifically it is a Dell Inspiron 2305 All in One touchscreen "thingy" that I am trying to convert into a touch screen monitor (with all peripherals included: usb, speakers, camera, IR, etc...) Through a KVM switch. (So I can use it as a standalone when needed)

I learned how to use the speakers, camera, digitizer (usb cables) But now I need a way to connect the screen.

**I dont know if im allowed to post the link, but the item im trying to learn more about is listed on Ebay as... 
 "(HDMI+DVI+VGA) Driver LVDS Inverter Kit - Convert a Bare Laptop LCD into Monitor"**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a Full HD Inspiron 9400 laptop LCD to a standalone monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/65640/converting-a-full-hd-inspiron-9400-laptop-lcd-to-a-standalone-monitor)

Comment: Reviewed post. 
Not a duplicate.

Comment: (for science) lol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by "LCD Inverter" you mean some sort of converter to connect the LCD's data ribbon cable to a VGA port.

If you mean the real inverter, which is a small, flat PCB involved in powering the LCD, you should examine closely the one in your AIO now and try to find the exact same model or compatible on Ebay.

If you mean the LCD display, all I can tell you with my limited experience in this area is:

- the signaling standard between the motherboard and LCD is likely FPD-Link, often mis-termed LVDS.
- I'm seeing LVDS and possibly FPD-Link to VGA converters on some simple Google searches, but I have no idea how you'd connect it to the LCD ribbon cable.
- I would bet the brightness is controlled via an I2C or CAN interface on that cable.  That's a wild guess.  I could and probably am horribly wrong.

Good luck.

Comment: I dont know if im allowed to post the link, but the item im trying to learn more about is listed on Ebay as "(HDMI+DVI+VGA) Driver LVDS Inverter Kit - Convert a Bare Laptop LCD into Monitor"